# google app script simulate external form submit button

Tags: forms, button, google-apps-script, submit

Is there any GAS example that explains how can I simulate the submit button of a given external site (not google site or form), and get the site results?

I have a site that gives me any company address (Portugal), based on the company name: this is a public site and I only have to enter the company name, press a submit button and get the main address, if it exists.

I need to find the addresses of about 1000 companies, and I would like to automate this boring task, since I have all companies complied in a single google sheet.

Thanks!
mdias

Comment: An alternate approach would be to copy the companies in an offline file (Excel, CSV, text file) and use a script (Perl, Python, etc.) that could retrieve the information from the website. These scripts have some modules/packages that ease the HTML requests.

Comment: Should be easy to do with UrlFetchApp if you know the url the form is posting data to and the format. You will need to provide that information if you want a real answer.